# WPF datagrid center vertical and horizontal alignment

Tags: wpf, datagrid, text-alignment

I have breaking my brain over this for a couple of hours now. I'm only trying to center my datagrid content vertical and horizontally. Every time something seems to work it gives other problems. My code currently is like the following:

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFA1A1A1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFA1A1A1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDDDDDD"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF3E3E42"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFA1A1A1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFD1D1D1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFA1A1A1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

With this code the text is aligned vertical and horizontally, but... There are two problems coming with this code.

1.) I can only select a row by clicking on the text. This needs to be the whole row.

2.) If I edit a column text then the vertical alignment will go from center to top. Also the textbox is only wrapped around the text.

I have tried almost every combination but it's not working. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I got point 2 working now. If somebody knows somethings about point 1, please let me know

Comment: What do you mean by "This needs to be the whole row"? A DataGrid's right most column might be empty in case the other columns don't fill up the full given space. The DataGrid doesn't allow to click into that empty column to select a row.

Comment: Well in my case 1 row stands for 1 object. Despite the fact that some columns can be empty. And I think it's better looking if a row click results in the whole row changing of looks. So I would still like to fix this, but thanks for your comment